# The issue of using the object of verb 'make'

Tags: word-usage

I have a question of using the object of 'make' verb.
Does the sentences below mean the same ?

1. Her appearance makes it a nice day.
2. Her appearance makes a day nice.
3. Her appearance makes for a nice day.

The additional question : why "it" occurs in the sentence 1. ?

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to tell what you are asking about. Both sentences are valid in English, if a little odd. We need to know what you are trying to communicate before we can provide a useful answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They all have the approximate meaning "I like to see her".

> Thorny underbrush makes for slow going.
>
> Rote repetition makes for boredom.
>
> Darkness makes it hard to see.
>
> Absence makes the heart grow fonder.
>
> Her laugh makes you want to scream.
>
> Practice makes perfect.

As we can see from these examples,  **make for** (because of the preposition **for**) wants a nominal complement.

**make** can take

a nominal complement followed by its own complement (it hard to see)

a nominal + infinitive-phrase complement (the heart grow fonder, you want to scream)

an adjective complement (perfect)

"it" is a proxy or placeholder referring to "things (as they are)". Read about "dummy it" or "expletive it".